# tinyMCE CustomField not editable

Tags: plugins, tinymce

i wrote a plugin for tinyMCE that includes "custom_fields" that can choise from a dropdownbox.
It works fine! But now i would a a second fild after the first one. But the result ist that the second field is IN the first, not next to each other!

The fields not have to be editable! Any ideas?

Comment: can you create a tinymce fiddle for this? (fiddle.tinymce.com)

Comment: Here is the fiddle: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/HKeaab

Comment: thanks for the fiddle. I am sorry, but i am still not able to grasp what you really want. Can you describe it a bit more exactly? (gerne auch in deutsch)

Comment: Ok vielen Dank, mein Problem ist das ich diese "Custom_Fields", gerne so hätte das diese nicht ineinander seien können! Wenn ich jetzt 2 Stück erstelle und mir dann den Quellcode anzeigen lasse so sehe ich das es in etwa so aussieht: 
<custom_field>Feld1<custom_field>Feld2</custom_field></custom_field>

Ich hätte es aber gerne so:
<custom_field>Feld1</custom_field><custom_field>Feld2</custom_field>

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this modiefied fiddle: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/YKeaab

The solution is to check if the common ancestor node is a custom_field node.
If yes select that node and insert the nodes outerHTML plus the new html and insert it into the editor:

```
onsubmit: function(e) {
    if(e.data.field!="")
                    {
                      var node = editor.selection.getNode();
                      var range = editor.selection.getRng(1);
                      if (node.nodeName == "CUSTOM_FIELD")
                      {
                          editor.selection.select(node);                    
                          editor.insertContent(node.outerHTML + '<custom_field>'+e.data.field+'</custom_field>');
                      }
                      else editor.insertContent('<custom_field>'+e.data.field+'</custom_field>');
                    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice! On my short test i found 2 problems...:
by 3 custom_fields it will happen again?!?! Thats confiusing me...

And 2. when i will write something after that field it will write in tha "custom_field"-tag

Comment: problem will be that you will be able to write into a custom field in case you click into that editor element

Comment: No i dont want to write in that field ;) it is ok if the field is "non editable" ;)

Comment: Maybe you should consider using something else (than a custom_filed) then. I can say from my own experiences that it is a pain in the ass to make sure that a user cannot write into a html elment in the editor.

Comment: Okay, also it is similar if the user can do this, but he should write after such an element and thats still impossible...